# ScriptAliasMatch not executing the expected script

Tags: apache2, mod-alias

I want to execute a perl script located in usr/lib/cgi-bin/script.pl when I get a GET request from client. 
The client request looks like this :

http://abc.xyz.com/60447/some.co.uk/MAIN0000000094884995-201309111452330000.nff?u=55313841&c=i&s=n

The above URL is dynamic from /60 ... and i want to execute the perl script in cgi-bin. 
The script has all permissions (chmod 777) and Runs when executed using perl command.

I tried with ScriptAliasMatch and ALiasMatch in apach2.conf but it doesnt seems working. 
Can anyone please suggest me what else need to be configured ?

Regards,
-Suresh

Comment: Can you give us more details? Like any errors from you apache log. Also I don't fully understand, are you trying to generate dynamic content from the perl script or do you intend to pass some part of the URL to your script?

Comment: Hi Ecelis..Thanks for your response. The issue is resolved now. I modified the regex I was using in ScriptAliasMatch and it started to work.